# Find $f'(x)$ at given value of x

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find $f'(x)$ at the given value of x

$f(x)=\sqrt{x+2}$

Find $f'(7)$

My question for this one is do I approach this question by trying to find the derivative of the initial equation and then once I have found the derivative do I simply plug in 7 for x and solve?

So once I start solving I would get $\frac{\sqrt{x+h+2}-\sqrt{x+2}}{h}$

$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sqrt{x+h+2}-\sqrt{x+2}}{h} = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sqrt{x+h+2}-\sqrt{x+2}}{h} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x+h+2}+\sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt{x+h+2}+\sqrt{x+2}}$

From that point I would get

$\frac{(x+h+2-x-2)}{h\sqrt{x+h+2}+\sqrt{x+2}}$

Comment: Yes, because that's what $f'(x)$ means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That is exactly how you do it!

Find $f'(x)$, then plug in $x=7$ into the resulting function and compute.

Here's how:

$$
\begin{align*}
f'(x)&=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sqrt{x+h+2}-\sqrt{x+2}}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{(\sqrt{x+h+2}-\sqrt{x+2})}{h} \cdot \frac{(\sqrt{x+h+2}+\sqrt{x+2})}{(\sqrt{x+h+2}+\sqrt{x+2})}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{x+h+2-x-2}{h(\sqrt{x+h+2}+\sqrt{x+2})}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h+2}+\sqrt{x+2}}\\
f'(x)&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+2}}
\end{align*}
$$

Now plugging in $x=7$ gives: $$f'(7)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{7+2}}=\frac{1}{6}.$$

Comment: "Solve" is not exactly the right word. There is nothing to solve there: "compute" is more appropriate.

Comment: Good point, thanks! Fixed.

Comment: So once I start solving I would get $\frac{\sqrt{x+h+2}-\sqrt{x+2}}{h}$Where would I go from there? I am just a little confused. I know I need to eliminate more variables to get the final answer but how would I do that.

Comment: Are you working with the formal definition of the derivative, or are can you use the fact that $f'(x^n)=nx^{n-1}$?

Comment: This is my first year of calculus so I believe that I am working with the formal definition as I do not have that formula anywhere in my notes

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer solving it by the formal definition of a derivative. I hope that helps.

Comment: So right before you got the derivative to plug 7 into how did you get rid of the initial x in the square root of x+h+2 on the bottom of the fraction. I know that the h disappears as you just plug in 0 for it but what about the x?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40739/discussion-between-user344249-and-m47145).

Answer (score 1):

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+2}}$$
$$f'(7)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{7+2}}=\frac{1}{6}$$

Comment: How did you get to this point $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+2}}$

Comment: $f(x)=(x+2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ Using the power rule, $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x+2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+2}}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Since you're using the difference quotient, you want to get rid of the square roots in the numerator by using the numerator's conjugate:

$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sqrt{x+h+2}-\sqrt{x+2}}{h} = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sqrt{x+h+2}-\sqrt{x+2}}{h} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x+h+2}+\sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt{x+h+2}+\sqrt{x+2}}$$

Comment: Which would then be $\frac{(x+h+2-x+2)}{h\sqrt{x+h+2}+\sqrt{x+2}}$  Which would then simply to $$\frac{(h+4)}{h\sqrt{x+h+2+\sqrt{x+2}}$

Comment: Two things, make sure first that you distribute the negative in the numerator, and that you put parentheses around the conjugate in the denominator. So, it should be $\frac{(x+h+2)-(x+2)}{h(\sqrt{x+h+2}+\sqrt{x+2})}$. Now try simplifying the numerator.

Answer (score 1):

The way you sketch -- first find $f'(x)$ in general -- would be right if you had a rule that allowed you to do that *easier* than going to the definition.

Specifically, for $f(x)=\sqrt{x+2}$ you would use the *chain rule* and the *power rule* that the deriviative of $x^n$ is $nx^{n-1}$, here with $n=\frac12$.

But if you don't have these two rules available, then there's no real reason to keep $x$ a variable while finding the limit. That's just more work that won't benefit you in this particular context. So since
$$ f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x+2+h}-\sqrt{x+2}}h $$
the first thing you should do, before worrying about the limit, is to plug in $x=7$:
$$ f'(7) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{9+h}-\sqrt{9}}h $$
and then you can look for the limit without being unduly distracted by the $x$.

(Hint for that: multiply by $\frac{\sqrt{9+h}+\sqrt 9}{\sqrt{9+h}+\sqrt{9}}$).

Answer (score 0):

Note that the numerator is the difference of two square roots. You can simplify this expression by multiplying the numerator and the denominator by the sum of the square roots.